# In sed how do I select a range between a pair of patterns only?

Tags: bash, sed

Let `+` and `-` be the patterns and say the file is the following:

```
+
-
some lines 1
-
some lines 2
+
some lines 3
-
+
some lines 4
```

If we were specify a range in sed, say so: `sed -n /+/,/-/ p` it would end up printing:

```
+
-
+
some lines 3
-
+
some lines 4
```

While the rest of it is alright, how do I not select `some lines 4` as it clearly isn't in between a pair of patterns.

Edit: There can be multiple lines between the `+` and `-` symbols. Also, it's not an option to remove all the lines following the last `-` prior to running this particular sed statement. Please keep in mind that this is a very generalized and reduced problem statement. I only need to know if there's a way to accomplish this is sed. It's hardly even snippet in the rest of the source, so anyone assuming I am out to get you to do my job, understand that that's not my intention.

Comment: What have you tried? Most of us here are happy to help you improve your craft, but are less happy acting as short order unpaid programming staff. Show us your work so far in an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), the result you were expecting and the results you got, and we'll help you figure it out.

Comment: could be there more than one line between `+` and `-`?

Comment: I suggest to use GNU grep: `grep -Poz '\+(\n.*?)*?-' file`

Comment: @ghoti A very rudimentary solution is to pre-process the file so that we can completely delete any line following the last `-` which is trivial and can be done in n number of ways including with sed. That's not a solution for me as this is a highly generalized question and I need that information later for some other purpose. Also, so far as MCVE goes, I don't think there's anything more apt in the world than `sed -n /+/,/-/ p`

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Yes, there can be. That's why I wrote some lines. I guess it's not clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save lines from `+` to `-` to GNU sed's hold space and only copy hold space back to pattern space if current line contains `-`.

```
sed -n '/+/,/-/{ /+/{h;b}; H; /-/{g;p} }' file
```

Output:

```
+
-
+
some lines 3
-
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answers, both this one and the one in the comments. The problem with this is that it occupies the hold space. I need to use it for processing some other things. Regards.

Comment: @debabrataroy Perhaps you should investigate the use of a different tool, such as `awk`. Sed has (many) limitations and complications like this are usually an indication that you've exceeded its capacity.

Comment: @DebabrataRoy: Maybe a second sed might help with your processing: `sed ... file | sed ...`

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/^+/{:a;N;/^-/M!ba;p}' file
```

Use seds grep-like switch `-n`. Gather up lines between start and end tokens and then explicitly print them. All other lines will not be printed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This will have issues if a `+` is followed by another `+` before we encounter a `-`.